# missing requirement osgi.wiring.package(com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.sax)

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, bndtools

I am trying to mix OSGi and JEE. I want to create a component in my Activator.java but when I console this project, I see following error:

```
could not resolve the bundles: [agenda.console-0.0.0Unresolved constraint in bundle agenda.console [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] osgi.wiring.package;(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.sax)]
```

**Activator.java**

[image: Activator]

**Bundels**:

[image: Bundels]

**MANIFEST of the JAR file**
[image: MANIFEST]

Thank you for your helps!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a class named `com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.sax.Properties`. What is that class and why are you using it? The name suggests it is internal and should not be used.

Probably you intended to use `java.util.Properties`. When you type a simple class name and then hit Ctrl-Space to complete the import for you, it's very important to pay attention to which class you are actually importing.

Comment: yes, I ignored the package which I imported, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

-runsystempackages: com.sun.xml

In your bndrun file.

Comment: I think your import for Properties is wrong. Try java.util.Properties

Comment: yes, I ignored the package, it's the java.util.Properties, thank you for pointing it out.